# Oracle Stored Procedure and bat File

Tags: sql, batch-file, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which truncates and inserts data into a few tables.

The stored procedure (.sql file) is called from bat file

```
echo off
sqlplus usr/pwd@wind < C:\temp\test.sql
```

It works fine.

Now, I need to return the status/result of the above procedure (pass/fail). And use that return in the bat file and pass it to the parent bat file (which generates a report).

I am unable to return and store the value in my bat file.

Appreciate any help.

below is a testing stored procedure

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
create or replace PROCEDURE hi
IS
    n NUMBER;
    Begin
    dbms_output.put_line( ' Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');
    End;

create or replace PROCEDURE hello
IS
    n NUMBER;
    Begin
    dbms_output.put_line( ' Helloooo');
    End;  

create or replace PROCEDURE ola(message VARCHAR)
IS
    n NUMBER;
    Begin
      if(message = 'hi')then
       hi;
     else
       hello;
      end if;
    End;
```

How do I get the message (hiiiiii/helloooo) in the bat file.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
`echo sqlplus usr/pwd@wind < C:\temp\test.sql`  or

`echo n | sqlplus usr/pwd@wind < C:\temp\test.sql`

and with help of environment variable get the result

Comment: Thank you. It worked. How do I access the value of 'n'?

Comment: Found a solution

FOR /F "usebackq delims=!" %%i IN (`sqlplus -S u/p@db @"C:\Users\or.sql"`) DO set STATUS=%%i


echo %STATUS%